# Creating an intro screen for a Java Applet

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

Hi guys I have a question about Applets. I have an game applet that I would like to embed in a webpage. However I would like to add a "Start Screen" to the applet which comes up first and has a few parameter buttons and a start button. The "Game Screen" should load when the start button is pressed. What would be the best way to go about implementing this? Here is a simple 1-screen Applet as an example.

```
 public class AppletExample extends Applet implements ActionListener{

Button okButton; 
Button cancelButton; 
TextField _textField;

public void init(){

    okButton = new Button("Press");
    cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    _textField = new TextField("Ready", 10);

    okButton.addActionListener(this);
    cancelButton.addActionListener(this);

    add(okButton);
    add(_textField);
    add(cancelButton);
    }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

if(arg0.getSource() == okButton){
    _textField.setText("Running...");
}
else {  _textField.setText("Cancelled");
}
}

 }
```

Comment: Applets can be configured to [show a custom loading screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/customizeLoadingScreen.html). The screen won't have input fields but it's a nice way to cut right in when the applet begins to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to manage navigation between panels.

Have a look also at using the lightweight Swing `JApplet` rather the old `AWT` `applet`. The start panel could be a `JPanel` containing the necessary components. Use [next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#next%28java.awt.Container%29), [previous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#previous%28java.awt.Container%29) or [show](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29) as appropriate to navigate between game panels.

```
public void init() {
   setLayout(new CardLayout());

   JPanel startPanel = new JPanel();
   okButton = new JButton("Press");
   startPanel.add(okButton);
   ...
   add(startPanel, "Card 1");
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but then in Swing how would you create a "start screen"? (Dont worry about the LayoutManager for now)

Comment: @phcoding: You are missing the point of `CardLayout`. Unlike other `LayoutManager`s, this one is really just a way to switch between visible `JPanel`s. Think a tabbed pane, but you are in full control of how and when the user can switch panels. One panel is your start screen and the other panel is the actual game.

Comment: Thanks for your help, from the answers here I am on the way to solving the problem.